# How do I relate a username table to equipment and employee tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a database with multiple tables and relationships. I'm working with Microsoft Access but the idea is to migrate to our Linux Server using MySQL.

I have a table for equipment (or any device that has an IP address, say a notebook, server, switches, and so on) and another table for employees (my design is a bit more complex than that but I simplified the problem for explaining purposes). I have another table for storing usernames, passwords, username roles and scope (local, domain, WordPress, e-mail, etc).

A simplified version of my problem in SQL (irrelevant fields have been omitted):

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
    IdEmployee INT NOT NULL,
    EmployeeName VARCHAR(50),
    EmployeeDepartment INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (IdEmployee)
);

CREATE TABLE devices (
    IdDevice INT NOT NULL,
    DeviceType INT,
    Brand INT,
    Model VARCHAR(30),
    PRIMARY KEY (IdDevice)
)

CREATE TABLE usernames (
    IdUsername INT NOT NULL,
    Username VARCHAR(20),
    Password VARCHAR(20),
    UserRole INT,
    UserScope INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (IdUsername)
)
```

The `Username` and `Password` fields are for storing the credentials for all of our routers, switches and multiple root users for our servers and databases. My design problem is: Employees have credentials for logging in our company's domain, also devices have credentials. But devices and employees don't have any fields in common so they have to be in separate tables. How do I relate the `usernames` table to `employees` and `devices` considering that:

- One employee may have more than one username (with different roles
  and scopes).
- Some employees even have the same username for different scopes (server, WordPress, etc).
- One device may or may not have more than one username
  (with different roles).
- Credentials for both employees and devices share the same characteristics (fields) so I would really not like to have two different tables for the same thing, but if I can't find a solution I guess I'll go with this.

The database itself is more complex; it covers a complete assets inventory and listing of all users and static IP addresses in our networks.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

Create two similar tables, EmployeeUsernames and DeviceUsernames:

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeUsernames (
    IdUsername INT NOT NULL,
    IdEmployee INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (IdUsername),
    FOREIGN KEY (IdEmployee) REFERENCES employees (IdEmployee),
    FOREIGN KEY (IdUsername) REFERENCES usernames (IdUsername)
);

CREATE TABLE DeviceUsernames (
    IdUsername INT NOT NULL,
    IdDevice INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (IdUsername),
    FOREIGN KEY (IdDevice) REFERENCES devices (IdDevice),
    FOREIGN KEY (IdUsername) REFERENCES usernames (IdUsername)
);
```

This allows for cases where there is no username and for cases where you have multiple usernames. If you wanted, you could add a check constraint or trigger to enforce any specific rules around the number of usernames in different situations.

**Option 2:**

You could put two columns into usernames - IdEmployee and IdDevice. Allow them to be null, and then use a check constraint or trigger to make sure that one column or the other is populated when data is inserted, and that the value inserted is valid (i.e. ensure the employee or device exists).

**Option 3:**

Add two columns into usernames - UsernameOwner and UsernameOwnerType. Put the IdEmployee or IdUsername value into the first column, and use the second to indicate which table that particular row is linked to. As above, use a check constraint or trigger to ensure the data remains valid.

---

Personally, I'd go with Option 1 - it's normalized, and will be less strange for someone else picking up the database and trying to understand how it hangs together, but some people really swear by one of the other options.